# Cancellable events through Publish-Subscribe pattern

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe

Based on lack of search results no matter how I word this, I'm pretty sure I'm thinking about this wrong.

I have a program that will be creating a large number of objects and there will be a number of events that should be wired up to listen to all the other instances, especially as soon as the instance is created. Managing this through pure events doesn't make sense to me. So that's my thought for using the pub/sub pattern to make things easier to handle. Also the plan is for the pub/sub to be purely in-process, so the events would not cross any boundaries. Also the events would not be persisted anywhere outside of memory, so there's no playback of events.

The problem comes with events that typically are [CancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx). **Is there a way to publish an event that subscribers can mark as being Cancelled?**

Here's my current thoughts at a possible solution:

- Publish a `ShouldCancelEventX` event and wait for some amount of time for an `EventXCancelled` event to be published back. If none are published in the time span, publish `EventX` event. The biggest issue I see with this is the arbitrary time span to wait for the events.
- Have the pub/sub implementation have a little more logic so that it can notify the publisher after all subscribers have received the event. This would allow the publisher of `ShouldCancelEventX` to know when all the subscribers have received the message. This just feels wrong as every implementation of pub/sub I've seen provides `void` Publish methods. So that, again, leads me to believe I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Comment: "Managing this through pure events doesn't make sense to me" - why? It sounds like you're overcomplicating things, but without knowing more about the situation it's difficult to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: @dtb The issue is that how do you notify every other instance in the system that another instance has been created and to wire up the appropriate event handlers. It also presents an issue for when to unwire the event handlers.

Comment: OK. So a producer creates a CancelEventArgs and sends it to the broker. The broker sends it to each subscriber that is interested in the event. Since "sending" here means invoking a method, why can't the subscriber set Cancel and, once all subscribers have been notified and the control returns to the publisher, the publisher retrieve Cancel from the CancelEventArgs?

Comment: Have you looked into [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)?

Comment: @dtb The biggest issue I see here is that the subscribers might not all be handling the event in a synchronous way. So simply waiting on all subscribers being called wouldn't be enough. Also I've looked into Rx, but every example I've seen still depends on the individual instances to publish events. If there's a more applicable example, please point me in a better direction.

Comment: If subscribers are working asynchronously, then they cannot give feedback on an event. So your right this doesn't work. What about something like publishing the event, but not acting on it. The subscribers process it asynchronously and, once they are done, publish it again. The original publisher is subscribed to completed events and acts an them. If a subscriber wants to cancel an event, it simply doesn't publish it.

Comment: Rx provides only the 'subscribe' part of publish-subscribe. You have to provide a broker yourself. A simple way to publish something in Rx is a Subject; you should be able to use that class to build a broker.

Comment: Have a look at the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but how would the original publisher know that all the potential subscribers have published the completed event? It gets back to the publisher having to be completely aware of all the subscribers available, which seems to defeat the purpose of a broker.

Comment: That's why I suggested the Chain-of-Responsibility pattern. The subscribers would not be notified in parallel, but in sequence. That is, once each subscriber is done, it passes the event on to the next subscriber. The last subscriber passes  the event back to the original publisher. You can implement cancellation by not passing an event on, or by setting a Cancel flag that lets the last subscriber know it shouldn't pass the event back to the original publisher. The broker is responsible for setting up the chains, so the publishers and subscribers do not have to worry about that.

Comment: If you want the subscribers to be notified in parallel, you need some kind of synchronization mechanism. For example, if the majority of subscribers is working asynchronously anyway, you could turn Publish and Notify into a Task. ContinueWith acting on the event WhenAll subscribers are done and none has requested cancellation.